# SQLite - There is any organization of data?

Tags: database, sqlite

I have a very simple question: After data are inserted, they will (anytime) be reorganized by SQLite?

E.g.:

```
_id   name
0    "Luke"
1    "Spock"
2    "Adama"
```

Can be reorganized (internally, without user interference) to something like this:

```
_id   name 
1    "Spock"
0    "Luke"
2    "Adama"
```

???

Comment: If you're asking whether or not SQLite has any inherent concept of row ordering, then, no.  Relational databases in general don't care about the order of rows in a table unless rows are being fetched for a query that includes an `order by` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a principle relational databases do not care about the ordering, unless you explicitly request it using `order by` statement.

Comment: Ok, then i can always count that the table will have the data in same order that was inserted?

Comment: No, that means that the order might be random if you're not using `order by`.

Comment: Was what i imagined.  Thanks! :-)

Comment: Plase accept an answer to close the question if you're satisfied :)

Comment: Done. I'm still getting used to the system used here. :-)